# Xamarin Datepicker Selected Index not selecting correct index

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

setting a selected index of a date picker containing a list of years from 1900, using the below code to select the current year

`

```
            yearpicker.ItemsSource = yearlist;

            var todayyear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            var findyear = yearlist.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(todayyear));

            yearpicker.SelectedIndex = findyear;
```

`

if you set a breakpoint the selected index returns "122" which is correct although the picker defaults to index 0. this only happens on android

unsure what could be causing this issue

Comment: What DatePicker are you using? Default xamarin forms DatePicker does not have ItemsSource and SelectedIndex attributes. Is this a custom picker?

Answer (score 0):

I have create a sample to test:

In the xaml:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
<Picker x:Name="picker" />  
 <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />
</StackLayout>
```

In the page.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        List<string> list;
        public MainPage()
        {    
            InitializeComponent();
            list  = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 1900; i< 2023; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            picker.ItemsSource = list;
        }
        private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var todayyear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            var findyear = list.FindIndex(x=>x.StartsWith(todayyear));
             picker.SelectedIndex = findyear;
        }
    }
```

When I clicked the button, the picker's current item will show `2022`. And the picker's range is from `1900` to `2022`. Everything is right. The index return 122 is also right. Because there is 123 items in the list, and the index is from 0 to 122.